# how do you get a negative decimal value from 8 bit signed binary number?

Tags: binary

for example, I have `i = 10110100`, why is it `-76`, shouldn't that be `180`?
I know it's `256-76=180`, but how can you tell when it's positive, and when its negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leftmost bit is the sign bit.  For an 8 bit signed number you have 7 bits for the number, and then the leftmost bit is the sign bit.

1 = negative,
0 = positive

An unsigned number is always positive, and all bits are for the number value itself.  For a signed 16 bit or 32 bit number, it is the same leftmost bit that tells it whether it is positive or negative, and the other rightmost 15 or 31 bits are for the number value.